# React portal event bubbling in the wrong direction

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, event-bubbling

In my app I created a React portal which consists of a div covering the entire document and contains a div (with some other content):

```
public render(): React.ReactNode {
    const { children, container = document.body } = this.props;
    const { open, options } = this.state;

    const className = this.getEffectiveClassNames([
        "portal",
        this.classFromProperty(options?.ignoreMouseEvents, "ignoreMouse"),
    ]);

    return (
        open && createPortal(
            <div
                ref={this.backgroundRef}
                className={className}
                style={{ "--background-opacity": options?.backgroundOpacity }}
                onMouseDown={this.handlePortalClick}
                {...this.unhandledProperties}
            >
                {children}
            </div>, container,
        )
    );
}
```

I want to hide the portal when the user clicks on the background div (not the content):

```
private handlePortalClick = (e: React.MouseEvent): void => {
    const { open, options } = this.state;

    if (open && options.closeOnPortalClick && e.target === this.backgroundRef.current) {
        this.close();
    }
};
```

I registered 2 mouse down handlers: one on the background div and one on the content. When I click on the content I first get the `onMouseDown` event for the background div and after that the handler for the content is triggered. This is odd, given that the content is a child of the background and I'm not using the capturing event handlers. In this situation I would expect to first get the event in the content handler and after that in the container.

Now I have to explicitly check if the event target is the background div, which works, but shouldn't be necessary. Can someone explain why the event invocation order is reversed in this case?

Comment: Third try: Look at this codesandbox. It's doesn't reproduce the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-kare-i1vjb?file=/src/App.js. The child handler is called first even though it is inside of the modal. How did you determine that the background handler is called first?

Comment: To see the order I added console.log calls in each of the mouse down handlers. Also during debugging I saw the same behavior.

Comment: So is my example from the sandbox equivalent to your code, because it doesn't seem to be reproduicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the misbehavior is a simple mistake. The portal click handler is not hooked up to `onClick` but to `onMouseDown` (while the content event handler is set to `onClick`). Since a click is generated from a mouse down, followed by a mouse up, the event chain is first run for the portal only (the content has no handler for that).

Answer (score 1):

I have created a minimal example of the setup you described but it doesn't show the behaviour described. The handler of the child gets called first:

```
const Child = () => {
  const handleMouseDown = e => console.log("child", e.currentTarget);

  return <div className="content" onMouseDown={handleMouseDown} />;
};

const Portal = ({ children }) => {
  const handleMouseDown = e => console.log("portal", e.currentTarget);

  return createPortal(
    <div className="background" onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}>
      {children}
    </div>,
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Portal>
        <Child />
      </Portal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit strange-kare-i1vjb]

If you don't want your background handler to be called if you click on the content you can add `event.stopPropagation()` to the handler in your child:

```
const Child = () => {
  const handleMouseDown = e => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      console.log("child", e.currentTarget);
  }

  return <div className="content" onMouseDown={handleMouseDown} />;
};
```

[image: Edit focused-breeze-em5bu]

Comment: Thanks for taking the burden to create a code example. I was afraid it would happen that this case is not reproducible, so I'm still clueless what is causing the effect I see. I triple checked the DOM hierarchy and the assigned handlers. It all looks perfectly ok.

Comment: Well did you check the console outputs of my code example? You can see that the handlers are called in the expected order. So can you spot any difference to your code that would explain that? It's not really possible to help if the problem can't be reproduced. How did you console log it? Can you show it?

Comment: Of course I checked it, otherwise I wouldn't have found that my case was not reproducible. Meanwhile however, I found my (stupid) mistake. I upvoted your attempt to help anyway.

Comment: @MikeLischke Thank you for that. Glad you found the problem yourself. The funny thing is I did the same mistake while creating the example. But I didn't think about that this could actually be the reason with your code too. haha

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI to anyone that may end up here: the solutions provided absolutely work, and just like `onMouseDown`, `onClick` should work so long as you're consistently using that as well.

I was seeing this same issue for a different reason, and just spun wheels for a while on the most inane mistake: I had a debugger inside of my child's event listener. It turns out, when I clicked on my child, I *was* successfully stopping propagation and avoiding the "close" behavior. When I was clicking the "play" button on the debugger within the Chrome window, however, I was inadvertently clicking on the parent, and seeing the console.log for the parent appear ‍♀️ This appeared, in the console, as if the parent's `onClick` was occurring first, but it actually had to do with the location of my debugger!